# Ajax execute only once inside an event

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have created a widget that displays a html template fetched with an ajax request to the server. I want to refresh the template clicking on a `<p>` element of the template. However when I click on it, it refreshes the template only once, then, if I try to click again, the event does not respond, it does not execute the request again. This is my code, if someone has any idea what I am doing wrong.

```
   /******** Our main function ********/
function main() {
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

        var widget_url = "/home/widget?callback=MyCallbackFunction"

        $.ajax({
            url: "/home/widget",
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "jsonp",
            jsonp: "callback",
            success: function (data) {

                $('#example-widget-container').html(data.html);

                $("#panel-sidebar-icon").on("click", function () {

                    $.ajax({
                        url: "/home/widget",
                        type: "GET",
                        dataType: "jsonp",
                        jsonp: "callback",
                        cache: false,
                        success: function (data) {
                            $('#example-widget-container').html(data.html);
                        }
                    });

                });
            }
        });                         


    });
}
```

The template example:

```
<aside> 
        <p id="panel-sidebar-icon">Click </p>
        <ul>
                <li>.... </li>              


        </ul>

</aside>
```

Comment: Try to put the `on("click")` event outside the `success` function

Comment: You can easily get rid of that duplicate code.

Comment: check that the <p> id is still the same, may have changed or try and use @T30 advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe because you create a new DOM object so the event goes with the erasure. You should update simple datas on the element or recreate the same component+event associated to it

Comment: i think it is what happens here. You are overriding the element, destroying the event related to it

Answer (score 2):

events attached to DOM elements are lost when you replace the container html, so.

change this

```
$("#panel-sidebar-icon").on("click", function () {
```

to this

```
$("body").on("click", "#panel-sidebar-icon", function () {
```